# Schedule Local Notification in iOS every first monday for each month of 2014

Tags: ios, date, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I want to get a `local notification` on my `iPhone` (iOS 4.3 on wards) on every first monday for each month of 2014 .

**For Eg.**

```
Feb 2014 - 2nd Feb First Monday  
March 2014 - 3rd March First Monday
```

Is there a simple logic to schedule this notification, please assist me with a snippet of code .

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276361/ios-set-local-notification-on-a-specific-day

Comment: can't we give a particular date as an argument for local notification ? Like 2 Feb , 3 rd march Etc.

Comment: Siddh let me check for this , i hope this is the thing which i was searching for