# Get a UILocalNotification to fire every week

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have set up a local notification to fire. I am wondering how to get it to repeat every week at the same time e.g., 9 AM on Monday.

Here's my code so far:

```
 @IBAction func scheduleLocal(sender: UIButton) {
guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() else { return
}
if settings.types == .None {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Cant Schedule", message: "No Permission", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate()
notification.alertBody = "Come Exercise"
notification.alertAction = "Exercise Time"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.userInfo = ["customField1": "w00t"]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad`:

```
 let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a repeatInterval you can set on the local notification that takes an NSCalendarUnit as its type. You can read more about the different available calendar units here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit

You would likely be looking for NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear

So you could just add the following to your code for your notification

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. So NSCalenderUnitWeekOfYear would repeat the notification infinitely at the same time on the same day each week?

Comment: Thank you. How would i go about setting the first fire date to for example 9:00am monday?

Comment: This answer can help you with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276361/ios-set-local-notification-on-a-specific-day

Comment: Is there a swift translation / explanation of this?

Comment: This question shows doing a daily notification which could be turned into a weekly notification using the WeekOfYear calendar unit for the repeat interval: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619998/repeating-local-notification-daily-at-a-set-time-with-swift

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.

But:
"Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

You can schedule the local notifications and recreate them each time the user open the app. Or use remote notifications instead.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I am trying to remind the users to take a break every hour between 9-5 on monday - friday. Would you recommend local notifications or remote notifcations for this?

Comment: I recommend local notifications. That give you fast schedule and weekly notifications for a year and quarter still if your user don't open the app.

Comment: How would i go about making a local notification repeat at the same time each week?

Comment: Just use a function like this and change the NSDate:

    - (void)scheduleAlert:(NSString*)alertBody fireDate:(NSDate*)fireDate{
    localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;

Comment: Does this also work for Swift as it looks like Objective C?

Comment: That is perfect!. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you can use event kit for this.