# Repeating Local Notifications every Week with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have an app using local notifications there is a total of 64 notifications, which is the limit of local notifications. I need to repeat each notification every week. I know that to set the repeat interval you use:

```
alarm.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit
```

I have tried using the .WeekOfYear and .WeekOfMonth. Do they repeat the notification every year or month? And I do not know the calendar unit for weekly. Which one can I use to repeat weekly?

Edit:

This is the code I am using to set the notifications.

```
let notifyAlarm = UILocalNotification()
let component = NSDateComponents()
component.hour = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Hour1")
component.minute = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Minute1")
component.weekday = 1

notifyAlarm.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(component)
notifyAlarm.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
notifyAlarm.alertBody = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Message1")
notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayOrdinal
notifyAlarm.soundName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Sound1")
app.scheduleLocalNotification(notifyAlarm)
```

I am setting 64 notifications like that at once. But with different dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the notification to fire for first time after a week you need to change the fire date.
I use TimeIntervalSinceNow for this, which is in seconds, so 1 week would be around 604000 seconds. 
You can use _ to separate numbers for legibility.

```
alarm.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 604_000)
```

Maybe a bit clunky but I think its the easiest for those type of notifications. I do something like this to make it easier.

```
struct NotificationFireDate {
    static let nextDay: NSTimeInterval = 85_000
    static let nextWeek: NSTimeInterval = 604_000
}
```

and than use it like so

```
alarm.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: NotificationFireDate.nextWeek)
```

Repeat interval should be weekOfYear

```
alarm.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
```

The first repeating notification should fire 1 week after the first (fireDate) notification fired.

For a full list have a look at this (thanks madmik3)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit

Comment: more details on the units here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit

Comment: Thanks, ill add it in my answer.

Comment: That repeats the notification every day of the week.

Comment: Sorry, my typo, copied the wrong code. It should be weekOfYear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781440/swift-how-to-get-a-local-notification-to-fire-every-week

Comment: The notification doesn't show at all with .WeekOfYear. Would that have anything do with 64 notifications because I know that it is the maximum.

Comment: What have you set for the fire date? Not sure about the limit, have you actually got 64 notifications set at once ?

Comment: I updated the question with the code for the notficiation.